# order rows in sql query based on which rows meet condition first

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know if there is anyway in sql server to order rows based on which rows meet the conditions first , for example if i am writing a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM IMAGES 
WHERE NAME LIKE '%TEST%'
AND DESCRIPTION LIKE '%TEST%'
```

I want rows that match the name to appear before rows that match the description , usually sql server will arrange them by their ID , so...anyway to do this ?! (note : I dont want to use union statement as that's gonna exhaust the database ).

Comment: `UNION` is not more exhausting than `LIKE '%sometext%'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the UNION would not necessarily exhaust the database; as written, it might not make a difference at all, performance-wise, depending on how the query optimizer decided to handle it.

Second, as your where clause contains an "AND", all your results will match on both description and name, so I don't think that's what you want.

Third, assuming you meant to have an "OR" in your query, you could try something like this:

```
select
    *
from
    images i
where 
    i.name like '%TEST%'
    or i.description like '%TEST%'
order by
    case
        when i.name like '%TEST%' then 0
        else 1
    end asc;
```

Comment: Okay thanks all for the replies...but again another problem appears , If i use any of the solutions , this will lead to data being ordered alphabetically ( which I dont want ) , I just want ones matching the first condition to appear first..I am just giving an example , It's not that I want to order rows by name or by description .

Comment: the solution I provided will not order by name or description.

Comment: Jeremy order by (number) will order by the column matching the number..right?!

Comment: no, `order by 1,2` is different from `order by <expression that equals a number>`.  The former will order by column ordinals, the latter by the value of the expression.

Comment: so zero means false and 1 means true based on expression ?! is there msdn article on this exactly to learn more about it ?

Comment: this is my final order by anyway for help ,

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN NAME LIKE N'%LOVE%' THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END ASC, 
   CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION LIKE N'%LOVE%' THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END ASC, 
   CASE WHEN TAGS LIKE N'%LOVE%' THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END ASC
     ) AS ROW_NUM

Comment: That's... really a lot of extra work for what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CASE` statements in your `ORDER BY` clause to get what you are after.

```
ORDER BY CASE(WHEN NAME LIKE '%TEST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

**EDIT:**

Sample code as proof of concept in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @t table(id int)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5)

SELECT *
FROM @t
ORDER BY(CASE WHEN id > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

Comment: what sort of syntax are you using for the CASE statement? I don't know of a single RDBMS where that would work.

Comment: ok, now I believe you. (without the end, I'd never heard -- I have seen the parens, but it's not in the SQL standard)

Comment: Okay thanks all for the replies...but again another problem appears , If i use any of the solutions , this will lead to data being ordered alphabetically ( which I dont want ) , I just want ones matching the first condition to appear first..I am just giving an example , It's not that I want to order rows by name or by description .

Comment: @MazenAbuTaweelih - if you want it in a particular order, you need to specify it.  There is no inherent order in SQL.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: using a case *expression* (not statement :) in the `ORDER BY` clause isn't allowed in Standard SQL at all! Note the `VALUES (1), (2), (3);` syntax is Standard SQL-92 supported in SQL Server 2008 and beyond.

Comment: try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by, or http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt, 13.1.2.b.  CASE is definitely allowed, as is any comparison clause, and it works in all major RDBMS's, so you might want to check your facts.  The above INSERT syntax, however, does not work in anything but SQL Server 2008 and higher (I haven't tried it, but I'll take your word for it), and Sql Server 2008 was not specified in the tags for this question.    By my reckoning, that makes your statements 1 for 3 (I stand corrected that it is an expression)

Comment: Hmm, that was a bit rude of me.  Why can't I edit my own comment?