# How to order query for searching where value = or is LIKE

Tags: mysql

I have a query that searches for stock numbers based on a user's input. I am trying to find the top 5 items that most closely match the input. If a stock number matches exactly, show that item first.

```
  SELECT
  ID, Stock
  FROM `store_items`
  WHERE Stock = '$query' OR Stock LIKE '%$query%' LIMIT 5
```

So, if in my database I have the following stock #'s:

```
MC-10
MC-11
MC-12
MC-100
MC-102
MC-103
```

And I search for `MC-10`, the exact result should show first, followed by other matches that it is LIKE:

```
MC-10
MC-100
MC-102
MC-103
```

How do I do the `ORDER BY` part of this query to make that happen?

Comment: You may look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744108/order-rows-in-sql-query-based-on-which-rows-meet-condition-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Stock,LOCATE('-', Stock) +1,  LENGTH(Stock) - LOCATE('-', Stock)) AS INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ORDER BY Stock = '$query' DESC
```

`TRUE` is treated as `1` and `FALSE` is `0`, so this will order the equal row first.

Answer (score 0):

I would order the result by Levenshtein distance to do this, but it may not be fast.

This place I grabbed an implementation of Levenshtein in MySQL from is: https://jonlabelle.com/snippets/view/sql/mysql-levenshtein-distance-algorithm

(I will not plagiarize for the answer as google will find you many examples)

Here is a fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/099a4/1 so your query will look like:

```
Select *, levenshtein_ratio('MC-10', productName) From ForgeRock WHERE productName like '%MC-10%' 
ORDER BY levenshtein_ratio('MC-10', productName) desc, productName ASC
```

Comment: If your need is straight forward and solved by the other two answers, this solution is overkill.